# Python concatenating two 2d arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

There is a lot about concatenating/appending arrays but I found nothing inbuild for my problem: Input:

```
A = [[0,0],
     [0,1],
     [1,0],
     [1,1]]
B = [[0],
     [1],
     [1],
     [0]]
```

Output:

```
C = [
     [[0,0],[0]],
     [[0,1],[1]],
     [[1,0],[1]],
     [[1,1],[0]]
    ]
```

I dont know how to solve this efficient ( inbuild? )

Comment: In numpy? Or as Python lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In vanilla python, this is easily done with a `map` and `zip`:

```
In [127]: C = list(map(list, zip(A, B)))

In [128]: C
Out[128]: [[[0, 0], [0]], 
           [[0, 1], [1]], 
           [[1, 0], [1]], 
           [[1, 1], [0]]]
```

The `zip` combines the two lists element-wise. The `map` is needed to convert each zipped element to a list.

With numpy.... you *could've* used `np.hstack` but they've not got the same dimensions, so, to my knowledge this cannot be done efficiently with numpy.

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage of Python is its support for [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

This is basically a one line loop which produces an array.

For your problem - and assuming you safeguarded that A and B always have the same length, you could easily write a single line of code like that:

```
[[A[i], B[i]] for i in range(len(A))]
```

which produces your desired output.

Comment: Or, as a simpler alternative, `[[x, y] for x, y in zip(A, B)]`.

Comment: Yes, that's simpler, but maybe more difficult when just starting with list comprehensions.

Comment: If the OP is talking numpy, one can only hope and pray they've got the basics down par.